# Updating a Set in Dynamo db using Node Js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, set, updates, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to do one of the most simple operations "Update" in a dynamo db list.

Table Schema -

```
businessId : String, customers: StringSet,  itemCode : NumberSet
```

I have an entry inserted via put -

```
bussinessId = "sampleBusiness", cuatomers 0: "cust1", itemCode 0: 4554
```

I want to add more items using update and here is what I have tried -

```
 var updateRequest = {  
    'TableName' : tableName,
    'Key' : {
        'businessId' : {
            "S" : businessId
        }
    },
    'UpdateExpression' : "SET itemCode[2] =:attrValue",    
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' : {
        ':attrValue' : {
            "N" : "564564"
        }
    }
};
```

This gives me error -

> Document Path provided in document is invalid

I wanted to append new entries so tried this as well -

```
var sm = [];
sm[0] = "56465";

//Add business to 
var updateRequest = {  
    'TableName' : tableName,
    'Key' : {
        'businessId' : {
            "S" : businessId
        }
    },
    'UpdateExpression' : 'SET #attrName = list_append(#attrName, :attrValue)',
    'ExpressionAttributeNames' : {
        '#attrName' : 'itemCode'
    },
    'ExpressionAttributeValues' : {
        ':attrValue' : {
            "NS" : sm
        }
    }
  };
```

This gives:

> ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: NS

Also attempted this -

```
 ':attrValue' : {
                "N" : "4564"
            }
```

But same error.

As per the example provided in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Modifying.html , it adds a new element to the `FiveStar` review list. The expression attribute name `#pr` is `ProductReviews`; the attribute value `:r` is a one-element list. If the list previously had two elements, [0] and [1], then the new element will be [2].

```
SET #pr.FiveStar = list_append(#pr.FiveStar, :r)
```

which Says `:r` is one element list

I am missing some thing here. Request if any one can help. Struck on this for long time. I just want to append elements in set in dynamo db using nodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this:

```
'ExpressionAttributeValues' : {
    ':attrValue' : {
        "NS" : sm
    }
}
```

Should be this:

```
'ExpressionAttributeValues' : {
    ':attrValue' : {
        "S" : sm
    }
}
```

Or you need to cast this value `sm[0] = "56465";` to a Number `Number("56465")` and change the `:attrValue` data type `"S"` to `"N"`. Depends on how you have your table configured.

It's possible too that you should assign `:attrValue` to be `"S" : sm[0]` because right now you are passing an `"S"` a whole array.

Answer (score -2):

I got a proper solution

```
var item = {"endTime": "7pm", "imageName": "7abcd", "startTime": "7pm"};

dynamo.updateItem({
    TableName:'TableName',
    Key:{"BucketName":"abcdefg" }, 
    UpdateExpression : "SET #attrName = list_append(#attrName, :attrValue)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames : {
        "#attrName" : "ImageLists"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':attrValue' : [item]
    }
},function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(data)
});
```